# Scala Future blocking with multiple Await.result() calls

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, future, blocking

I don't understand why this example, taken from [here](https://github.com/sergiuszkierat/scala-best-practices/blob/master/sections/4-concurrency-parallelism.md), is blocking

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("Start")
    implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1))
    println("Made ec")
    def addOne(x: Int) = {
      println("Executing addOne")
      Future(x)
    }

    def multiply(x: Int, y: Int): Future[Int] = Future {
      val a = addOne(x)
      val b = addOne(y)
      val result: Future[Int] = for (r1 <- a; r2 <- b) yield r1 * r2
      println("Got result")
      val awaitedResult: Int = Await.result(result, Duration.Inf)
      println("awaitedResult = " + awaitedResult)
      awaitedResult
    }
    val mult: Future[Int] = multiply(2,2)
    val multResult: Int = Await.result(mult, Duration.Inf)
    println("Result of mult = " + multResult)
  }
}
```

Output of IntelliJ Scala Project:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:36346', transport: 'socket'
Start
Made ec
Executing addOne
Executing addOne
Got result
awaitedResult = 4
Result of mult = 4
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:36346', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 130
```

Note:

```
    Hot Swap failed Main: hierarchy change not implemented;
    Main: Operation not supported by VM
```

The weird thing is that in the IntelliJ console, I see the answer, 4, but I have to click the red "stop" button because it won't terminate.

Comment: Why is this blocking? Because you block every time you call `Await.result`, this is exactly what this method does, it blocks till `Future` ends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things at play here:

1. You don't close your `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)` thread pool. Call `shutdownNow()` on it at the end, otherwise the non-daemon threads block Java exit.
2. The second thing is that you need more than one thread in your thread pool because the single thread is blocked by multiple `Await` calls.

**Why you need more than one thread:** If you add a debug message before waiting for multiplication

```
val mult: Future[Int] = multiply(2,2)
println("before multiplication")
val multResult: Int = Await.result(mult, Duration.Inf)
```

You will see that the output may be

```
Made ec
before multiplication result
Executing addOne
...
```

As you can see, call to `multiply(2,2)` just constructs a Future containing a prescription of your computation but doesn't necessarily execute anything.

Here is how you can hit a deadlock: First, `Await.result(mult, Duration.Inf)` triggers the `multiply()` method and blocks the main thread. Body of `multiply()` is executed on the single thread pool thread. Then we hit `Await.result(result, Duration.Inf)`. This again triggers computation of the `result` value and blocks the thread pool thread. And that's where we hit a deadlock: thread pool is blocked by waiting for `Await.result(result, Duration.Inf)` but there's no other thread where `result` value can be computed.

**How to do with single thread:** Generally, you should await your futures only at the latest possible point where you need the result. That's why Scala makes it more difficult to await compared to Java. So the correct approach is to avoid await in `multiply()`:

```
def multiply(x: Int, y: Int): Future[Int] = {
  val a = addOne(x)
  val b = addOne(y)
  val result: Future[Int] = for (r1 <- a; r2 <- b) yield r1 * r2
  println("Got result")
  result.andThen{ case Success(i) => println("awaitedResult = " +i) }
}
```

The article you link also talks about `blocking { ... }`. This may help if you use the standard execution context, but not with a custom thread pool, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19682155/2032064).