# how works scala future async and how is it related to nodejs evented async

Tags: multithreading, scala, asynchronous, akka, future

I've a lot of doubts related to scala future and how it works, basically I was reading this article about scala async using futures

**Play Framework: async I/O without the thread pool and callback hell**
http://engineering.linkedin.com/play/play-framework-async-io-without-thread-pool-and-callback-hell

the author talk about how hard is handle async programming using thread pools..and explain how async futures works in scala, but this article generates me more questions:

I thought than scala async worked using a thread pool, is it evented async similar to how nodejs works?

I did a small test building a slow server which wait 1 second before response..then (using scala version 2.11.0-M5 and futures from  scala.concurrent._ ) I did 100 request to the server

the result are obvious, it tooks a bit more than 100 seconds in complete all the request...
now the async code

```
        implicit val executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8) //I also test without fixing the thread pool 

        implicit val executionContext = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(executorService)
              val myFuture = future{
                    blocking{
                    .  ..long request here

              })}
              }

       myFuture.onComplete{
                    case Success(_) => ....
                    case _ => ....
              }
```

I have understood than if I don't fix my thread pool in my executorService, scala based in how many cores has my pc defines how many threads must to take...

running this..the complete test tooks "100/8" seconds aprox, is ok but is not what I would expect from an evented system, seems more related to thread pool where my threads blocks, is it ok??..is what would you expect?

**blocking** is not avoiding than my code blocks and I don't know the reasons..

my question so far are:

1) what happen **if I run scala futures with only a thread?**..Would expect a similar behaviour to nodejs, which runs in a single thread and is evented async?...in my dummy test scala async scale based in how many threads I defined previously (so basically it doesnt avoid the thread pool hell)

2) In this answer from Heather Miller

[Asynchronous IO in Scala with futures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13097754/asynchronous-io-in-scala-with-futures)

she gives the impression than when I've a blocking code inside, scala spawn a new worker preventing starvation , but in my example seems not works as expected and my code finally blocks, what am I doing wrong?...

3) What could be the reasons of why my code blocks?...are there some rules  I should know when use promises/futures?

4) **What is the difference between scala futures,akka futures and twitter futures?**..Could I have a total different results based in which tool I choose?...

**NOTICE:** I fix the thread pool because I was running the sample in a single core architecture (vertx.io)..without it I got not results (scala took only a single thread and it blocks in every request)

**NOTICE 2** I'm not so familiar with threads execution  and probably I did several mistakes in the terminology than I used...

Comment: the article really says "this use a thread pool from behind"? What does "from behind" mean? can you show us where this is said, I think perhaps there was a mistranslation.

Comment: clarified the real focus of my question, thanks..

Comment: I also created a similar test using Scala Play 2, it's also blocking.