# bad use cases of scala.concurrent.blocking?

Tags: scala, concurrency, blocking

With reference to the third point in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19682155/383053) accepted answer, are there any cases for which it would be pointless or bad to use `blocking` for a long-running computation, whether CPU- or IO-bound, that is being executed 'within' a `Future`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the `ExecutionContext` your `Future` is being executed in.

**Pointless:**

If the `ExecutionContext` is not a `BlockContext`, then using `blocking` will be pointless. That is, it would use the [DefaultBlockContext](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/092690e7bf71bb22e6e57afb7ea7f67fdfe31a0a/src/library/scala/concurrent/BlockContext.scala#L52-54), which simply executes the code without any special handling. It probably wouldn't add that much overhead, but pointless nonetheless.

**Bad:**

Scala's `ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` is made to spawn new threads in a `ForkJoinPool` when the thread pool is about to be exhausted. That is, if it *knows* that is going to happen via `blocking`. This can be bad if you're spawning *lots* of threads. If you're queuing up a lot of work in a short span of time, the `global` context will happily expand until gridlock. @dk14's answer explains this in more depth, but the gist is that it can be a performance killer as managed blocking can actually become quickly unmanageable.

---

The main purpose of `blocking` is to avoid deadlocks within thread pools, so it is tangentially related to performance in the sense that reaching a deadlock would be worse than spawning a few more threads. However, it is definitely not a magical performance enhancer.

I've written more about `blocking` in particular in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29069021/2292812).

Comment: by the way, maybe you know any other blocking-aware implementations than `ForkJoinPool`? I didn't find...

Answer (score 5):

[From my practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28044971/how-to-guarantee-sequentiality-for-forks-in-akka), `blocking`  + `ForkJoinPool` may lead to contionuous and uncontrollable creation of threads if you have a lot of messages  to process and each one requires long blocking (which also means that it holds some memory during such). `ForkJoinPool` creates new thread to compensate the "managable blocked" one, regardless of `MaxThreadCount`; say hello to hundreds of threads in VisualVm. And it almost kills backpressure, as there is always a place for task in the pool's queue (if your backpressure is based on  `ThreadPoolExecutor`'s policies). Performance becomes killed by both new-thread-allocation and garbage collection.

So:

- it's good when message rate is not much higher than 1/blocking_time as it allows you to use full power of threads. Some smart backpressure might help to slow down incoming messages.
- It's pointless if a task actually uses your CPU during `blocking{}` (no locks), as it will just increase counts of threads more than count of real cores in system.
- And bad for any other cases - you should use separate fixed thread-pool (and maybe polling) then.

P.S. `blocking` is hidden inside `Await.result`, so it's not always obvious. In our project someone just did such `Await` inside some underlying worker actor.