# scala, spray, akka - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread

Tags: scala, akka, spray

While checking the throughput of spray api.

Scenario: 25 concurrent users

Os: Free BSD

Memory: 2GB

No Of Cores: 2

At around 13 concurrent users i was getting the following error.

```
[ERROR] [06/29/2015 05:01:56.407] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2]     [ActorSystem(default)] Uncaught error from thread [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:714)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.tryAddWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1672)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.deregisterWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1795)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:117)
```

Akka and Spray Conf changes from default:

```
akka{
    tcp{
        register-timeout = 20s
    }
}

spray.can {
    request-timeout = 30 s
    bind-timeout = 30s
    unbind-timeout = 5s
    registration-timeout = 30s
}

http.spray.can {
    server{
        pipelining-limit = 50
    }
}
```

What is causing the OutOfMemmoryError. The exception is thrown from the **router actor**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

can't read mind, but probably you do blocking (`Await.result` or similar) inside actors. `ForkJoinPool` creates a new thread for every blocked one automatically. So if you have a long-time blocks count_of_threads == count_of_requests (+ every thread holds the references iside call stack),  which eventually causes `OutOfMemory`.

See, [Blocking Needs Careful Management](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/dispatchers.html#blocking-needs-careful-management)

P.S. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29663410/bad-use-cases-of-scala-concurrent-blocking) you may find why `Await.result` (which uses `scala.concurrent.blocking` inside) leads to unmanageable creation of threads in `ForkJoinPool`(even regardless of `maxParallelism`).

---

Or you creating a lot of `ActorSystem`s, [same page of akka documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/actor-systems.html) states:

> An ActorSystem is a heavyweight structure that will allocate 1…N
>   Threads, so create one per logical application.

Comment: I was making Await.result inside actors. Now i removed that and made it to Future. But other actors have blocking calls such as REST calls. Will that be the issue.

Comment: Had 2 actor systems in the application. Now made it to one and seems to be working. Can you please explain the change in behavior.

Comment: As I said, I can't read mind :) - less actor systems - less memory, so it could help a bit. But two actor systems isn't enough to be a direct reason of this exception (maybe you had "`def`" factory with a lot of actor systems - then it could be a problem). Are you sure that ActorSystem removing helped or it actually was removing of `Await.result`?Answering your first question - blocking REST calls probably won't cause this exception (however it's still bad) because their blocking is unmanagable and `ForkJoinPool` knows nothing about them so it won't create new thread for.

Comment: Got it. I was creating an actor system inside an actor, such that every time that actor is called it will create an actor system. :) Thanks for your quick help.

Comment: Np. Added this to the answer to make it correct one.