# Why can't Actors complete all work although I created 10000 of them?

Tags: scala, akka

I create 10000 actors and send a message to each, but it seems that the akka system can't complete all the work.
when I check the thread state, they are all in `TIMED_WATIING`.

My code:

```
class Reciver extends Actor {
  val log = Logging(context.system, this)
  var num = 0

  def receive = {
    case a: Int => log.info(s"[${self.path}] receive $a, num is $num")
      Thread.sleep(2000)
      log.info(s"[${self.path}] processing $a, num is $num")
      num = a
  }
}

object ActorSyncOrAsync extends App {
  val system = ActorSystem("mysys")

  for (i <- 0 to 10000) {
    val actor = system.actorOf(Props[Reciver])
    actor ! i
  }
  println("main thread send request complete")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should remove `Thread.sleep` or (if you're using default thread-pool) surround it with:

```
scala.concurrent.blocking { 
  Thread.sleep(2000)
}
```

`scala.concurrent.blocking` marks the computation to have a managed blocking, which means that it tells the pool that computation is not taking CPU resources but just waits for some result or timeout. You should [be careful with this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29663410/bad-use-cases-of-scala-concurrent-blocking) however. So, basically, this advice works if you're using `Thread.sleep` for debugging purposes or just to emulate some activity - no `Thread.sleep` (even surrounded by `blocking`) should take place in production code.

**Explanation**:

When some fixed pool is used (including fork-join as it doesn't steal work from threads blocked by `Thread.sleep`) - there is only POOL_SIZE threads (it equals to the number of cores in your system by default) is used for computation. Everything else is going to be queued.

So, let's say 4 cores, 2 seconds per task, 10000 tasks - it's gonna take 2*10000/4 = 5000 seconds.

The general advice is to **not block** (including `Thread.sleep`) inside your actors: [Blocking needs careful management](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/general/actor-systems.html#Blocking_Needs_Careful_Management). If you need to delay some action it's better to use Scheduler (as @Lukasz mentioned):  http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.4/scala/scheduler.html

Comment: He probably just should use scheduler to perform the part of processing message after sleep and remove sleep altogether.

Comment: @Lukasz I believe Thread.sleep was just for debugging purposes, but I'll add this info to the answer as well. Thanks!