# Asynchronous IO (socket) in Scala

Tags: scala, future

```
import java.nio.channels.{AsynchronousServerSocketChannel, AsynchronousSocketChannel}
import java.net.InetSocketAddress
import scala.concurrent.{Future, blocking}

class Master {
  val server: AsynchronousServerSocketChannel = AsynchronousServerSocketChannel.open()
  server.bind(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", port))

  val client: Future[AsynchronousSocketChannel] = Future { blocking { server.accept().get() } }
}
```

This is a pseudo code what I'm trying.

Before asking this question, I searched about it and found a related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13097754/asynchronous-io-in-scala-with-futures#answer-13099594).
In her answer, I wonder what this means: `"If you want to absolutely prevent additional threads from ever being created, then you ought to use an AsyncIO library, such as Java's NIO library."`

Since I don't want to suffer from either `running out of memory` (case when using `blocking`) or `thread pool hell` (opposite case) , her answer was exactly what I have been looking forward. However, as you can see in my pseudo code, a new thread will be created for each client (I made just one client for the sake of simplicity) due to `blocking` even though I used NIO as she said.

1. Please explain her suggestion with a simple example.
2. Is my pseudo code an appropriate approach when trying to asynchronous io in Scala or is there a better alternative way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer to Question 1**

She suggests two things

a) If you are using future with blocking call then use `scala.concurrent.blocking`. `blocking` tells the default execution context to spawn temporary threads to stop starvation.

lets say `blockingServe()` does blocking.  To do multiple `blockingServe`s we use Futures.

```
Future {
  blockingServe() //blockingServe() could be serverSocket.accept()
}
```

But above code leads to starvation in evented model. In order to deal with starvation. We have to ask execution context to create new temporary threads to serve extra requests. This is communicated to execution context using `scala.concurrent.blocking`

```
Future {
  blocking {
    blockingServe() //blockingServe() could be serverSocket.accept()
  }
}
```

b)

**We have not achieved non-blocking still. Code is still blocking but blocking in different thread (asynchronous)**

*How can we achieve true non blocking ?*

We can achieve true non-blocking using `non-blocking api`.

So, in your case you have to use `java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel` to go for true non blocking model.

*Notice in your code snippet you have mixed a) and b) which not required*

**Answer to Question 2**

```
 val selector = Selector.open()
 val serverChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open()
 serverChannel.configureBlocking(false)
 serverChannel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress("192.168.2.1", 5000))
 serverChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT)
 def assignWork[A](serverChannel: ServerSocketChannel, selector: Selector, work:  => Future[A]) = {

   work
   //recurse
 }
 assignWork[Unit](serverChannel, selector, Future(()))
}
```

Comment: Now I got it. What I was confused was the difference between `non-blocking` and `asynchronous`. However, after reading somewhat polling code, I changed my mind. I'll choose  the asynchronous way for the simple code even though it consumes more threads. In this case, is my pseudo code the best?

Comment: @illuxic Yes. you can go for the blocking version of `nio` library